python / TkInter Entry value sometimes got, sometimes not
I am facing an issue that looks strange to me.
I just want my program to get the data entered by the user in an Entry field and print it in the std out.
for so I use TkInter and an Entry widget, bound to a StringVar and a button to trigger the display.
when I make a single window, that is to say the Entry is in the main window, all runs smoothly.
though, when this very window is displayed after pressing a button on a parent window, things go wrong ... the get() on the StringVar looks getting nothing.
As you may see, this is the same code in both cases.
Any ideas ? It looks like a bug, but as I am a bit noob ...
Here is my code :
import tkinter as tk

case = 2

def main():

    def cb_create():
        create()

    if case == 1:
        main_window = tk.Tk()
        w = tk.Button(main_window, text="Create", bg="red", fg="white", width=25, command=cb_create)
        w.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=10)
        main_window.mainloop()
    else:
        cb_create()

def create():

    window = tk.Tk()
    window.config(bg="lightgrey")

    s_name = tk.StringVar()

    def cb_add():
        print(f"<<<{s_name.get()}>>>")
        add(s_name.get())

    tk.Label(window, text="Name", bg="lightgrey").grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E)
    tk.Entry(window, bd=3, textvariable=s_name).grid(row=2, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)

    tk.Button(window, text="Add", bg="red", fg="white", width=10,
              command=cb_add).grid(row=7, column=3, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)

    if case == 2:
        window.mainloop()

def add(name):
    print(f">>>{name}<<<")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Regards !
I have isolated the issue as most as I could in the code, and I tried googling.
"TkInter entry not accessible", "issue TkInter getting data from Entry", ... (without the quotes of course)
no way
I expect to have the entry value displayed between ">>>" and "<<<" in both cases
value is displayed only in the configuration when the window is the main one.
when the window is a child, no value is displayed ">>><<<"
output in case 2 (right behavior) :
<<<foo>>>
\>>>foo<<<
output in case 1 (wrong behavior):
<<<>>>
\>>><<<

It is because you have more than one instance of Tk().  Use Toplevel() for child windows.

It is because for case = 1, there are two instances of Tk() created.
In this case, the tkinter StringVar() is created inside the first instance of Tk() if its parent is not specified, so it cannot be linked to the entry widget created inside the second instance of Tk().
Either specify the parent when creating the instance of StringVar() as below:
s_name = tk.StringVar(window)

or use Toplevel() instead of Tk() when window is a child window.
